# How do you set up the line integral $\int_{\gamma} \alpha$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms, line-integrals

Let $\alpha = dx_1 - x_1^{-1} dx_2$ and we have $\gamma(t) = (t^2, t^3)$, where $t$ is between $0$ and $1$.

Are we going to do something like this

$$\gamma'(t) = 2t d1 + 3t^2 d2.$$

Then $\alpha(\gamma') = 2t - 3x_1t^2$ and then we can plug in $t^2$ for $x_1$ and get

$$2t - 3t^4$$
and then integrate that from $0$ to $1$?

How would you confirm or deny the fact that you could solve this using the end points alone (line integrals)?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It's not clear what are those $d1$, $d2$

Comment: The d's on the d1 and d2 are the curved d from something like partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. To clean up and clear up notation I will start from the beginning. The differential 1-form $\alpha$ is notation for the following

$$\int_{\gamma} P(x_1,x_2)\; dx_1 + Q(x_1,x_2) \; dx_2=\int_{\gamma} P(x_1,x_2)\; dx_1 + \int_{\gamma} Q(x_1,x_2)\; dx_2$$

which can be evaluated over a parameterization $\gamma(t)$ as

$$\int_{\gamma(t)} P\big(x_1(t),x_2(t)\big)\; \frac{dx_1}{dt}\;dt + \int_{\gamma(t)} Q\big(x_1(t),x_2(t)\big)\; \frac{dx_2}{dt}\; dt \;\; .$$

We can clearly combine this into one integral involving $t$ and for your case this ends up being

$$\int_0^1 (1)(2t) - (t^{-2})(3t^2) \; dt = \int_0^1 2t - 3 \; dt \;\; .$$

Aside from some inconvenient notational choices, your only error was that you used $\alpha = dx_1 - x_1 dx_2$ instead of $\alpha = dx_1 - x_1^{-1} dx_2$ as the problem statement dictates.

Comment: Sweet thanks for the help! That really helps me clean up the notation!

Answer (score 0):

> How would you confirm or deny the fact that you could solve this using the end points alone (line integrals)?

Common confusion. You've plugged in the equation of curve into the one form. As you change the parameter of $t$, you are essentially moving along the curve $\gamma(t) = (t^2,t^3)$, so when you plug in the bounds of the parameter, you are actually taking the final coordinates on the curve.

So, at $t=1$, the point one curve is: $(1,1)$
And at $t=0$ , it is at $(0,0)$

So the curve is in such a way that it starts at the origin for the initial value of the parameter and ends at $(1,1)$ in the final value.

Comment: But if it can be evaluated at the end points alone shouldn't the you get the same answer when evaluating the integral and when you plug in the end points to the curve? The integral ends up being 2t - 3 dt which becomes t^2 - 3t and when you plug the end points in you get -2. What are you supposed to plug 0 and 1 into to try and verify endpoints alone work?